# Laravel 5.4: How to add service layer files?

Tags: php, laravel, service, makefile, laravel-artisan

I need to add service layer in my project where controllers are doing all work now.

Can I use PHP artisan to make service files, as we do for controllers: `php artisan make:controller` ?

How do you add service files?

Comment: what you mean by service? you want to create service provider?

Comment: @PandhiBhaumik, No, I mean the service layer where you define all business logic instead of the controller. Have a look here: https://m.dotdev.co/design-pattern-service-layer-with-laravel-5-740ff0a7b65f

Comment: you can use laravel [repository](https://github.com/andersao/l5-repository)

Comment: Nothing comes as a service layer (between your controller and model) out of the box in Laravel. You are free to implement your own layer or use something as suggested above by @PandhiBhaumik.

Comment: @mustafa-ehsan basically I wanted to know, do you write the service file from scratch yourself or is there a tool like php artisan make:controller to create the service file?

Comment: @chuck you write it yourself. There is no generator like artisan for it.

Comment: @chuck, why don't you go through doc link I sent you, it might help you. but there is no inbuilt functionality for service in Laravel

Answer (score 0):

I'll leave an answer just in case someone is also looking for it.

No, there is not such thing as service layer out of the box in Laravel, you should either implement it yourself or you can require a repository which implements it https://github.com/TakeoO/laravel-service-layer